# Extracting data with awk when some lines have empty/missing values

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep, gawk

I have a sample  as shown here:

> input.txt

```
   USERS        position   ref   rslt   
    usr1                    X     B   
    usr2          2980            C   
    usr3          3323      P      
    usr4                          A  
    usr5          5251      U      
    usr6          9990            A
    usr7          10345     T
```

I need to print "rslt" column and corresponding "USERS", output file should be like this:

> output.txt

```
  USERS     rslt   
   usr1       B   
   usr2       C       
   usr4       A
   usr6       A
```

I tried to use `awk`command but it didn't work. Note that, all black position of the table is filled with spaces (No. of spaces is different in each row)

Comment: can you edit input file by marking a '$' as end of line ?

Comment: I can manipulate `input.txt` as long as it helps to get `output.txt`

Comment: I just want to see in your sample field lenght, if it is fixed length, then we can see if last char is non space.

Answer (score 12):

In this case, one possible solution is to provide the widths of the fields
in the beginning section:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS = "16 11 6 7"} 
    $4 ~/[^ ]/ {print $1 $4}'
```

Fieldwidths may be counted by hand, but for complex headers I like to start with

```
 head -1 f | grep -Po '.*? (?=\S|$)' | awk '{print length}'
```

UPDATE: ... or in order to deal with initial and final spaces in the header:

```
 head -1 f | grep -Po '(^ *|\S).*?( (?=\S)|$)' | awk '{print length}'
```

Comment: Well, I didn't get it. where from you get these values? `FIELDWIDTHS = "16 10 6 7"`

Comment: I suggest to count them by hand (or by `head -1 x | grep -Po '.*? (?=\S|$)' | awk '{print length}'` )

Answer (score 6):

The *awk* command isn't the most appropriate tool for this job.  Use *cut*, which takes as an argument the character positions of the fields you want to extract.  So in your example specify that `USERS` starts from character position 1 and ends in character position 8 and `rslt` starts on character position 33.

```
$ cut -c 1-8,33- input.txt
   USERS rslt
    usr1  B
    usr2  C
    usr3
    usr4  A
    usr5
    usr6  A
    usr7
```

See the following on how to count character positions.

```
         1         2         3         
123456789012345678901234567890123456789
   USERS        position   ref   rslt   
    usr1                    X     B   
    usr2          2980            C   
    usr3          3323      P      
    usr4                          A  
    usr5          5251      U      
    usr6          9990            A
    usr7          10345     T
```

Comment: cool! (+1) I also liked numeration rule : it helps the reader.

Answer (score 1):

You can get *almost* there by using the `unexpand` utility to 'tabify' the input, then setting the `awk` field separator to tab and only printing lines whose final field consist of something other than spaces:

```
unexpand -t8 input.txt | awk -F'\t' '$NF ~ /[^ ]/ {print $1, $NF}'
    usr1   B
    usr2   C
    usr4   A
    usr6   A
```

It doesn't work for the header line because there are fewer spaces between the `position` and `ref` fields. If the header is a must have, you could handle that separately:

```
unexpand -t8 input.txt | awk -F'\t' 'NR == 1 {print $1,$3} $NF ~ /[^ ]/ {print $1, $NF}'
```